# How to access Azure config at runtime in Python

Tags: python, azure, cscfg

I am building a worker role built with Python (in a .pyproj) using the Azure SDK.  I would like to be able to access settings defined in the role's .cscfg configuration file at runtime.  The SDK readme implies that this can be done, but I cannot find a means to access this configuration data using the Python SDK.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: We ended up going a different route, but I did find this in the bowels of our repo. I believe it was as simple as accessing the environment, i.e.

``os.environ[SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY]``

Comment: i found this in the end which sounds similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591436/azure-environment-variables-in-python-cloud-service